# in Chrome browser, links are not clickable if they lie over a Video element with controls

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, hyperlink, controls

I have a video element in an HTML5 document. There is a control panel div that slides out dynamically to partially cover the video element.

This works fine in Firefox and IE9. However, in Google Chrome, any part of any link that lies over the Video element, is not clickable. The pointer doesn't change when you mouseover the link, and clicking the link has no effect.

The problem is fixed if I set the Video element to not display controls. But oddly, if the Video element starts with controls enabled, and then I remove the Controls attribute dynamically, the links are unclickable. I've tried using both jQuery and regular JavaScript.

At present, I don't need the controls to be shown, so my page is ok. But I'd like to understand the problem better (plus, if somebody else has the same problem, perhaps this post will help them?). Does naybody know, is there some difference to how Chrome handles the video element, compared to IE9 and FF?

Comment: Did you try changing z-order?

Comment: Yes - and if the z-order had been wrong, then I'd have thought the links would have been hidden behind the video object? (also wouldn't the problem have happened in all browsers?) And as I say, turning off the controls made it work.

Comment: As controls are in a separate "object" (I assume), they can have different z-order to the video container, so the links would not necessarily be hidden. Browsers are different in their implementations, so it's normal (unfortunately) to have strange things happenning only in one of them. It could be worth posting some code and a screenshot.

Comment: My code example is too long to post in a comment, so I have put it on LiveJournal: http://littlebrain2.livejournal.com/654.html

This shows two video objects, one has controls one doesn't. In Chrome, I cannot click on the text that lies over the video object with controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added `z-index` to both overlapping elements in your code, and it works for me ok. For example, CSS for first `div` is changed to:

```
div.first {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 255;
}
```

And first `video` is changed to:

```
<video controls style="z-index:0">
```

I can click the link inside the first `div`, including that part floating over `video` element.

Comment: Thanks! That does indeed work on my machine too. I feel really dumb now - I must have not tried a high enough z-index, or else I did something else stupid.

It's still add that the problem only occurs in Chrome, with Controls  enabled, but I guess that's the joy of browsers ;)

Thanks again!